# interesting case of docker rmi and prune failure

Tags: image, docker

I installed `vimagick/mediagoblin` for testing purposes. Next I wanted to get rid of that image. No problem with other images. No chance with this one.

After trying all I could find, this is what happens and it is reproducible.

```
root@IONOS_1: /root # sudo docker rmi -f f78c79138fb7
Untagged: vimagick/mediagoblin@sha256:7be300b7b484d8b15a38c3da2957809092fa94de23304a3b7469db3e9c2496f9
Deleted: sha256:f78c79138fb77df81dcc33c5d439495a481844c4e53d07a296827c2931c2db9c
Deleted: sha256:290aed1d6949dcc02629dd8c1b01eeb1540871bacff6ef64ca608c9aabc1aa2f
Deleted: sha256:c85cdfb9999e3cf32b9154bad24694f4503c50a374f888a0b7c2e84a71a741d2
Deleted: sha256:90b8298e50cbb1e913e1923c6b97be9cde62b65e4ce02197e927455939e9f245
Deleted: sha256:90a01990c55fb696c76a4205b539e267c0230a1fe41ac012938f4b29bc474438
Deleted: sha256:8d4d1ab5ff74fc361fb74212fff3b6dc1e6c16d1e1f0e8b44f9a9112b00b564f
```

Now this looks like everything is ok. It is not. I repeat this command:

```
root@IONOS_1: /root # sudo docker rmi -f f78c79138fb7
Untagged: vimagick/mediagoblin@sha256:7be300b7b484d8b15a38c3da2957809092fa94de23304a3b7469db3e9c2496f9
Deleted: sha256:f78c79138fb77df81dcc33c5d439495a481844c4e53d07a296827c2931c2db9c
Deleted: sha256:290aed1d6949dcc02629dd8c1b01eeb1540871bacff6ef64ca608c9aabc1aa2f
Deleted: sha256:c85cdfb9999e3cf32b9154bad24694f4503c50a374f888a0b7c2e84a71a741d2
Deleted: sha256:90b8298e50cbb1e913e1923c6b97be9cde62b65e4ce02197e927455939e9f245
Deleted: sha256:90a01990c55fb696c76a4205b539e267c0230a1fe41ac012938f4b29bc474438
Deleted: sha256:8d4d1ab5ff74fc361fb74212fff3b6dc1e6c16d1e1f0e8b44f9a9112b00b564f
```

Same result. If the first command would have been successful, we would not have this result, right?

Take a bigger gun now:

```
root@IONOS_1: /root # docker system prune -a -f --volumes
Deleted Images:
untagged: vimagick/mediagoblin@sha256:7be300b7b484d8b15a38c3da2957809092fa94de23304a3b7469db3e9c2496f9
deleted: sha256:f78c79138fb77df81dcc33c5d439495a481844c4e53d07a296827c2931c2db9c
deleted: sha256:290aed1d6949dcc02629dd8c1b01eeb1540871bacff6ef64ca608c9aabc1aa2f
deleted: sha256:c85cdfb9999e3cf32b9154bad24694f4503c50a374f888a0b7c2e84a71a741d2
deleted: sha256:90b8298e50cbb1e913e1923c6b97be9cde62b65e4ce02197e927455939e9f245
deleted: sha256:90a01990c55fb696c76a4205b539e267c0230a1fe41ac012938f4b29bc474438
deleted: sha256:8d4d1ab5ff74fc361fb74212fff3b6dc1e6c16d1e1f0e8b44f9a9112b00b564f
untagged: linuxserver/piwigo@sha256:2f67a305ea2ca83832aa101af1289f68a74b8a811068895882e8f2bbbc0dff72

Total reclaimed space: 1.205GB
```

Now this looks really good, doesn't it?

```
root@IONOS_1: /root # docker images  | grep "vimag"
```

No output. All good. Really? No, it isn't. After some time

```
root@IONOS_1: /root # docker images  | grep "vimag"
vimagick/mediagoblin                   <none>              f78c79138fb7        3 years ago         1.21GB
```

I can repeat this endlessly.

```
root@IONOS_1: /root # docker system prune -a -f --volumes
Deleted Images:
untagged: vimagick/mediagoblin@sha256:7be300b7b484d8b15a38c3da2957809092fa94de23304a3b7469db3e9c2496f9
deleted: sha256:f78c79138fb77df81dcc33c5d439495a481844c4e53d07a296827c2931c2db9c
deleted: sha256:290aed1d6949dcc02629dd8c1b01eeb1540871bacff6ef64ca608c9aabc1aa2f
deleted: sha256:c85cdfb9999e3cf32b9154bad24694f4503c50a374f888a0b7c2e84a71a741d2
deleted: sha256:90b8298e50cbb1e913e1923c6b97be9cde62b65e4ce02197e927455939e9f245
deleted: sha256:90a01990c55fb696c76a4205b539e267c0230a1fe41ac012938f4b29bc474438
deleted: sha256:8d4d1ab5ff74fc361fb74212fff3b6dc1e6c16d1e1f0e8b44f9a9112b00b564f

Total reclaimed space: 1.205GB
```

What happens here?

Comment: Is a cron job or something else launching a container, that's causing the image to get pulled again?  Does `docker ps -a` show it?

Comment: No. Besides, if docker tells me reclaimed space, where should that container come from?

Comment: Later I had to take down the stack and saw to my surprise `Removing service wp_mediagoblin`. This service was not shown with `docker ps -a`. That's another anomaly. No surprise, the image `vimagick/mediagoblin` was back. Incidentally, still later I filled my disk to 100% so I had to make room. Again, I reclaimed space, filled it up with other stuff, and since then `vimagick/mediagoblin` din't appear again, even when I freed that space again.

Comment: So the hypotheses is then that the deletion of the container and the reclamation of space failed because of some dangling not running instance in the stack. The success message was wrong. When taking the stack down, the zombie container was freed and the deletion then was real. The reclamation of space was real, too, because I could use it for other stuff. New question: How do you produce such a zombie container?